# How to expose only one particular class from an assembly?

Tags: c#, oop, assemblies

Suppose assembly Assembly1.dll contains 3 classes: Class C1, C2, C3.

I want to expose only class C1 to the outside world. Classes C2 and C3 will not be accessible. How to acheive this?

Note: Making classes C2 and C3 private is not an option as this will make them unaccessible inside the assembly itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make classes C2 and C3 internal, as in:

```
internal class C2
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, you use `internal` visibility. A couple more points though:

- For non-nested types, internal is actually the default in C#, so you don't *have* to specify it. Whether or not you explicitly specify the default access is a matter of personal taste. (I'm currently on the fence, leaning towards being explicit.)
- Only nested types can be private in the first place - and again, that's the default visibility for nested types.

Comment: Wasn't public the default in .NET 1.* ? To me, that in itself is a perfect reason for being explicit...

Comment: @Carl: No, the default hasn't changed over time.

Answer (score 5):

The "internal" keyword specifies that a class is accessible only within its own assembly.  Perhaps you should tag C2 and C3 with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) keyword.

Some more links.

[Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)
[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "internal" accessor instead of "private" so your classes visibility will be confined to assembly level and not outside.

Answer (score 1):

`internal` is the way to go. If you want to test your classes C2 and C3 from a different assembly, you can do this by setting the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute on your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The internal keyword works fine if you don't want to expose your classes to both COM and .NET outside your assembly.

However if you want finer control over what you expose to COM the way to do it is leave your classes as public, uncheck 'Make Assembly COM Visible' in the project Properties (which changes AssemblyInfo.cs under the covers) and then add an attribute to the class you want to expose to COM. Something like this:

```
[Guid("12338758-70B4-40B7-75FA-50300015DAC9")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyClassToExpose
```